# Google Script by recording not appearing in the Macros menu

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I have recorded scripts that work in the editor and will run from the editor but the same script is not being picked up in the Google Sheet macros menu that it was recorded from

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: What do you mean by "I have recorded scripts"? What steps do you followed to do that?